# Please, how do i resolve the validation error at admin("" value must be an integer)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin, validationerror

Whenever i launch the server and i try to access the admin page, i often get the ValidationError: ['test@user.com' value must be an integer].

I had created custom user for the project and done the necessary settings(admin.py,model.py,forms.py) as instructed in the documentation. I have also tried to write an authentification backend in settings.py but lead to another error.
But could not figure out why the pk is using USERNAME_FIELD as the pk.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    username        = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    email           = models.EmailField(
                        max_length=200,
                        unique=True,
                    )
    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # confirm         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # confirm_date    = models.DateTimeField(default=False)
    # phone_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=40)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  940.             return int(value)

During handling of the above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test@user.com'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in wrapper
  241.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  212.             if not self.has_permission(request):

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in has_permission
  186.         return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  213.             self._setup()

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in _setup
  347.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py" in <lambda>
  24.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py" in get_user
  12.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in get_user
  182.         user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in _get_user_session_key
  59.     return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])

File "C:\Users\Ayo Paul\.virtualenvs\python_and_Django_web_development-NQaQovYW\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  945.                 params={'value': value},

Exception Type: ValidationError at /admin/
Exception Value: ["'test@user.com' value must be an integer."]



class ClientAuthBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):


        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid Credentials")


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: What's inside the `user_id` field?

Comment: Pls i don't understand that question,please

Comment: my suspicion is that you stored your email on the user_id field, can you query your database to see the content of the user_id field?

Comment: The problem is what is stored in `request.session[SESSION_KEY]`. How have you set that? Do you have a custom auth backend?

Comment: please, take a look at custom auth backend.thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

remove that "unique = True".

Comment: this answer is totally useless - the `unique` arg, while useless for a a primary key (which is unique by definition), doesn't change the column's type.